# Correct way to setup a function call from event?

Tags: jquery

Is this the way to setup my event to call a function?

I have this in a document.ready

```
$(document).on('change', "[data-viewlink]",
    function ()
    {
        UpdateViewLink($(this).attr("id"));
    }
);
```

The `UpdateViewLink()` function is surrounded by a `function()`. It is a single call and am wondering if `function(){}` is required. Is this the correct way to set this up?

I also call `UpdateViewLink()` from normal functions.

Comment: what do you intend to pass into UpdateViewLink ?

Comment: Depends on the implementation of UpdateViewLink. You can't pass parameters to it (except for the jQuery-provided `this` to) if you don't use a closure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is required if you really want to pass the id as an argument to `UpdateViewLink`.

However, you may use this instead:

```
$(document).on('change', "[data-viewlink]", UpdateViewLink);
```

The id of the changed element will be available  inside `UpdateViewLink` as `this.id`. So it depends on whether you can modify `UpdateViewLink`, or not.

Comment: Also, avoid `$(this).attr("id")`. There's no need to create a new jQuery object just to access the id, which is directly accessible as `this.id` on any DOM node.